# keybord shortcut to minimize all windows in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu

I want the keyboard shortcut to minimize all windows in Ubuntu 
and how to modify default shortcut in **Ubuntu 17.04**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To minimize all windows in ubuntu press Ctrl + Super + D (ctrl+windows+D). its default shortcut to minimize all windows.

you can change it by goto: System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Comment: Also working only with (windows + D) 

Comment: Also works on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4):

short answer  for minimize all windows is:

<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>